# Preventing deleting button, when row deleted

Tags: vba, excel

I 've the following problem. I wrote a macro that deletes empty rows and assigned this macro to a button. But when I run this macro, if my button is located on empty row, it is also deleted. How to prevent button from being deleted? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

1. Right click on the button
2. Click on Format Control
3. Under the properties tab, select `Don't move or size with cells` and you are done.

[image]

Comment: I would just like to add that if you have the buttons grouped into a shape you must also select this property for the shape itself as well as the buttons.